# SPRESENSE SDKでのGPIO制御関数の使用について

Tags: spresense, gpio

SPRESENSE SDK にてGPIO制御をしようとしています。

下記をインクルードした上で
board_gpio_configやboard_gpio_writeを使おうとしたのですが、
エラーメッセージが出て使えませんでした。

これらの関数を使うために何か特別な設定が必要でしょうか？

SPRESENSE SDKのバージョンは1.3と1.5を試し同じ結果でした。
Windows10環境で、MSYS2 MSYSを使っています。

インクルード：

```
#include <arch/board/board.h>
#include <arch/chip/pin.h>
```

メイン関数内での記述：

```
board_gpio_config(97,0,false,true,0);
board_gpio_write(97,1);
```

エラーメッセージ：

```
undefined reference to `board_gpio_config'
undefined reference to `board_gpio_write'
```

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

(追記)
y_waiwai さん、Fumu 7 さん、回答ありがとうございます。

上記の `#include <arch/board/board.h>` の中で、`cxd56_gpioif.h` が include されております。
念のため追加で cxd56_gpioif.h を include しても改善されませんでした。

関数名のスペルも合っていそうです。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/api-reference/api-references-spresense-sdk/group__gpioif.html

これらの関数を使うためには、上記 include では十分でなく、何か Config に対する設定や、Lib の設定などが必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: `undefined reference` は「コンパイル時」でなくて「リンク時」のエラーなので、ご推察の通りライブラリが足らないのです（今資料がないのでこれだけ）

Answer (score 0):

board_gpio_configとboard_gpio_writeが定義されてないというエラーです。
ヘッダファイルの中でこれらの関数が定義されてるところを探してみてはどうでしょう

Answer (score 0):

Spresense SDK Library のページ　https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/api-reference/api-references-spresense-sdk/group__gpioif.html#ga1844b81ca3136ecb8c4a3d4bb3f36677
を見ると、board_gpio_configやboard_gpio_writeは、cxd56_gpioif.h　に書かれているようです。

```
#include <cxd56_gpioif.h>
```

という行をインクルードの最後に追加すると良いかもしれません。
（当方、SPRESENSEを持っていないので、確認できていません）